# Is there a way to run a for loop query based on datagridview selected values in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Unable to get the excepted result due to the following error

> Conversion from string " to type 'integer' is not valid'

I have been able to load values from the products table, add selected ones to Selected Products and then search all the selected products against the Customers table to find out how many customers ordered these products.

```vb
Try
    Dim ListOfDiag As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In SelectedDiagDGV.Rows
        ListOfDiag.Append(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "", "" & Environment.NewLine)
    Next

    Dim query As String = String.Empty
    Dim SegmentConnectionString As String = "Data Source=Test-PC;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"
    query = "SELECT Customers, ProductName from Customers WHERE ProductName in (" & ListOfDiag.ToString & ")"
    Dim dTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim dAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    dAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query, SegmentConnectionString)
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dTable

    'Next
Catch ex As System. Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

Unable to perform a for loop search. Some of the values contain special characters example: Soft ’Drink’; Computer (Desk).

> Error: Conversion from string " to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Side Note: please look at using parameters and using statements. On another note, the code above will not even compile, `"SELECT * Customers, ProductName from Customers
        "WHERE ProductName in (" & ListOfDiag.ToString & ")"` that alone is your issue. There are other syntax/potential issues here, but the actual query string is an issue as well as `ListOfDiag.Append`.

Comment: How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I edited your code to compile and be more readable. please confirm the issue still exists.

Comment: @Facekianda Instead of using `IN` you can use a table-valued parameter so that the query can use a `JOIN` instead and the values are passed as parameters so that "special" characters are no longer special (i.e. there is no chance of SQL injection attacks or problems with `'`). [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) has comprehensive information on that.

Comment: Get rid of the `Try...Catch...End Try` temporarily so you can see which line is producing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListOfDiag.Append(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "", "" & Environment.NewLine)`

There is no overload of `StringBuilder.Append` that takes `(String, String)` as arguments. the first string is `row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & ""` and then there is a comma between parameters and the second string is `"" & Environment.NewLine` Remember that "" is an empty string, not escape characters. Not sure what your intention was but this will not work.

You had the right approach; to build a string for the `In` clause. I used a `List(Of String)` to get the data from the rows then after the loop I used a `.Join` with a comma separator to get the value for the `In` clause.

I passed the connection string directly to the constructor of the Connection and passed the Select statement and the connection to the constructor of the Command. For the Select statement I used and Interpolated String (the string preceded by the $) You could also use String.Format in older version of Visual Studio.

The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

I think the only special character that could mess things up would be the presence of a comma in a Product Name.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dTable As New DataTable
    Dim ListOfDiag As New List(Of String)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In SelectedDiagDGV.Rows
        ListOfDiag.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
    Next
    Dim InData = String.Join(",", ListOfDiag)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Test-PC;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand($"SELECT Customers, ProductName from Customers WHERE ProductName in ({InData})", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dTable
End Sub
```